# What is the badge for a person who viewed a Tumbleweed's question?

Tags: feature-request, tumbleweed-badge

**Seriously in lighter vein:** I have acquired the Tumbleweed badge for asking a question on astyle, as it had "attracted" low number (actually zero) of views, comments or answers. Almost after three months, I got my reputation topped by five because somebody had viewed it. Should there be a badge too for viewing a Tumbleweed question?

Comment: I'd be rich....

Comment: You actually got +5 rep because someone up voted your question, not because someone viewed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think there should be a badge for viewing a tumbleweed question.

The tumbleweed badge is mostly a consolation prize.  It could be a really great question, a diamond in the rough, or it could be a really poor question that slipped through the cracks of community moderation.  It could also have been posted on a low-traffic tag.

What would be the criteria for awarding?  Could it be awarded more than once?  Would users abuse this badge by digging up old questions without votes?

Additionally, if a question has low activity like that for a year, it is automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the badge for a person who viewed a Tumbleweed's question?

The [Reversal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258).

Yeah, I know.  You have to do more than just *look* at the question.  Yeah, I know.  It requires answering a question with score of -5.  I'm proud of my reversal badge.  There's only been 257 handed out in SO's entire history.

The point, of course, is that I actually had to *do something* to earn that badge.

Comment: The Reversal badge requires the question to have a score of -5 of lower, while the Tumblewood requires the question to have a score of 0. While it's not impossible, I doubt that this happened at all in the SO history.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Fixed.  Don't bother with the SEDE query.

Comment: I can't check ^^ in SEDE because it doesn't store the post ID of a badge :(